# Android Studio: importing a bunch of images in the mipmap folder

Tags: android

Is there any way to import a bunch of images/icons in the mipmap folder (assigning each icon to the correct folder according to its resolution) without importing manually each single image?

Basically I have an old project and would like to use a subset of the icons in a new one. I have copied all the folders inside of `mipmap`  from the old to the new project, restarted Android Studio, but nothing happens.

Comment: "but nothing happens" -- what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: The minimum was copy&past between two different AS projects